# How to set event start date to a text view

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am finding it difficult to set the Value of the start date which i get from my device calendar on click of a textfield.
I have a textfield as Date and when I click on the textfield it open up event calendar of my device. What i want to achieve is to set the Start date to the textfield when saved its clicked on the event calendar.
Below is my code for getting the event celendar on click of my textfield Date.

```
public  void caln(){
Date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

    final    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()  + 60 * 60 * 1000;



        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,endTime);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Neel Birthday"+ Firstname.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,  "This is a sample description");
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "My Guest House");
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=YEARLY");

        startActivity(intent);

    }

}

);
}
```

[image: event calendar view]

When I click save, i want the value in the Start Date to set on the text field Date.

I have tried

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String passedvaluefromformeractivity = intent.getExtras().getString(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME);
    Date.setText(""+passedvaluefromformeractivity);
```

But getting errors.
Please your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has been Resolved. By setting the start date from the my textfiled